# Dart inspect() function, doesn't seem to do anything in VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using VS Code.

Supposedly there is a function called inspect() in dart that allows you to vardump an object.

my barebones example is as follows:

```
import 'dart:developer';

class User {
  String name;
  int age;

  User(this.name, this.age);
}

void main() {
  User newUser = User("Steve", 30);
  inspect(newUser);
  print('done');
}
```

I don't get any errors, but all I see in the Debug Console is "done"

On this page there is am image showing inspect() sample output (4th image from the top) in the Debug Console:
[Link](https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-12/)

Is there something else I need to do to make this command work in VS Code?